# Can i have a fact table with few descriptive attributes

Tags: data-warehouse, business-intelligence

I know fact should contain measures but there is a scenario where I want some descriptive attributes in my reports because just plain ID from fact table business wouldn't understand it.

Shall I join my fact table to dimensions to pull such attributes and create a new table for reporting??

Shall fact table always have measures or can it also have some descriptive attributes so that i can avoid the above steps?

Examples from Kimball always shows there are just measures in suppose transaction facts

Comment: You join your fact table to dimension tables to satisfy each and every query.

Comment: thanks, is this the only best approach @GilbertLeBlanc ?

Answer (score 0):

Shall I join my fact table to dimensions to pull such attributes and create a new table for reporting??

-- Yes, but you won't necessarily need to create a new table for the result. The result will go to your report.

Shall fact table always have measures or can it also have some descriptive attributes so that i can avoid the above steps?

-- This is also possible and not wrong, as long as the attributes are not too much. Please note that this depends on your memory, performance etc, etc.

The key is to find the balance you need between the design explained in answer 1 and answer 2.

Comment: Does your first point mean you are calculating things on the fly?

Comment: Let's say you're doing a sum on a measure column in the fact table and joining this with the dimension tables to get the descriptive attributes and your result will go on a report (which will be cached by browser, reporting software etc.)

You can also do aggregations on the fact table and store them in a separate table, let's say aggregate table and join that table with the dimension tables to get descriptive data.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a junk dimension where you basically put everything else that do not fit in existing dimension and you do not want to track over time.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension_(data_warehouse)#Junk_dimension

> A Junk Dimension is a dimension table consisting of attributes that do
> not belong in the fact table or in any of the existing dimension
> tables. The nature of these attributes is usually text or various
> flags, e.g. non-generic comments or just simple yes/no or true/false
> indicators. These kinds of attributes are typically remaining when all
> the obvious dimensions in the business process have been identified
> and thus the designer is faced with the challenge of where to put
> these attributes that do not belong in the other dimensions.